# Regex to match periods but not between numbers

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex to match a string that contains a word from the previous period to the next period but if a number with a period is in in between, I want it to match the next period.

So in:

> Hello. This is an example. This is an example. This is an 4.815
> example.

I wanto to match:

```
This is an example
This is another example.
This is an 4.815 example.
```

For now I have this regex but it breaks at the period in "4.815"

```
([^.]+)example[^.]*
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be

```
[^.]*(?:(?:\.\d)[^.]*)*example[^.]*(?:(?:\.\d)[^.]*)*\.
```

The pattern matches

- `[^.]*(?:(?:\.\d)[^.]*)*` Match any char except a dot, only when the dot is followed by a digit
- `example` Match literally
- `[^.]*(?:(?:\.\d)[^.]*)*` Match any char except a dot, only when the dot is followed by a digit
- `\.` Match a literal dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lynfLn/1)

Or without the leading whitspace

```
(?<!\S)[^.]*(?:(?:\.\d)[^.]*)*example[^.]*(?:(?:\.\d)[^.]*)*\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nRddsk/1)